How do I solve Unable to establish connection on channel
On startup the application works fine but when I change activities and return to the map activity/page then the error pops causing the app to crash.
Error trace:
(https://i.sstatic.net/TU2hSJjW.png)
Script:
Future<void> _goToTheLake(double lat, double lng) async {
    try {
      if(lat != null && lng != null) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          final GoogleMapController controller = await  mapController.future;
          print('GoogleMapController initialized');
          await controller.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
                  bearing: 192.8334901395799,
                  target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                  tilt: 59.440717697143555,
                  zoom: 15.151926040649414)));
          print('Camera animated to new position on Android');


        } else {
          final apple.AppleMapController controller = await appleMapController
              .future;
          print('AppleMapController initialized');
          await controller.animateCamera(
              apple.CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(apple.CameraPosition(
                  target: apple.LatLng(lat, lng),
                  zoom: 15.151926040649414)));
          print('Camera animated to new position on iOS');
        }
      }else{
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception: $e');
    }
  }


Could you please check out this post if it can help you with your problem?
